# iOS PKPKT BLE concept

Tags: ios, iphone, bluetooth

I understand that the iOS App "[PKPKT](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/pkpkt/id687362268?ls=1&mt=8)" is using BLE (Bluetooth Low Enery). But what I am curious about it is, is it purely using BLE only? Or does it switching between BLE and Classic Bluetooth?

I tested with a iPhone 5 and a iPhone 5s with both installed the app. I turned on bluetooth on both devices. And then i checked the "DEVICES" list to see if the other iPhone is paired with one another, I found that they are not. Until i launched the PKPKT on one of the device, and the i check the "DEVICE" list again, now they are paired and connected. So, i'm thinking is this pairing done by the BLE pairing? Meaning one of "Just works", "Out of Band", or "Passkey entry" methods.

There is also a "**Chat**" functionality in that app. This make me curious if the chatting function using **BLE** or **Classic Bluetooth**?

So my question is actually "**Is switching between BLE and Classic bluetooth possible?**". This is part of the study on this BLE technology. Hopefully someone could help me and other newbie on this new technology.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I wrote PKPKT. I only use BLE. No classic. iBeacon is cool but doesn't have the background scanning needed to discover other players. I use game center, but only for scores, no sessions. It's optional in the app to enable game center (those banners can be distracting!)

The chat is also over BLE.

Because the connections are not encrypted, you don't need to manually pair the devices, and "just works"

Comment: hmm...thx for the info.. the term "iBeacon" does it means some "CLBeacon.." classes in CoreLocation library ?https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/navigation/#section=Frameworks&topic=CoreLocation

Answer (score 1):

I think you might find [this](http://vivianaranha.com/apple-gamekit-bluetooth-integration-tutorial/) link helpful. It implements something that looks to be a simpler version of PKPKT. I believe the app uses a combination of GameKit/iBeacon. The app requires iOS7.0+ and states, "PKPKT does the hard work of finding other players by detecting them using Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE) in the background." iBeacon would be the most battery-efficient way of accomplishing this and is a new feature in iOS 7. There is a wealth of information online(particularly on SO) about peer to peer bluetooth gaming using GameKit, if you are interested.

We can't say for sure unless the developer lets us know. If one were to attempt to recreate the application, GameKit and iBeacon would be the technologies that I believe most would recommend.

Comment: hmmm....guess u r right...what really happen in the backend we really couldn't know. Thx for the link!

Answer (score 1):

You might find this project helpful as an overview of how to use Bluetooth LE to communicate between two devices. You don't need to pair the devices, and unlike iBeacons, it works when the app is in the background.

[SimpleShare - Easy Proximity-based Sharing for iOS](http://github.com/lauraskelton/simple-share)

You can use the delegate methods of the SimpleShare project to easily share arrays of strings between nearby users running your app, such as user IDs, which you could then use to get more info, photos, etc, about that user from a web service.